# Debian Stretch: Mosquitto Unit mosquitto.service is masked

Tags: raspberry-pi3, mosquitto, debian-stretch

I'm trying to set up mosquitto under RPi - Debian Stretch.

sudo service mosquitto giving me following returncode:

```
Failed to start mosquitto.service: Unit mosquitto.service is masked.
```

sudo service mosquitto status:

```
● mosquitto.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Can somebody give me a hint how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Fix it with
sudo systemctl unmask mosquitto service
sudo service mosquitto stop
sudo service mosquitto start

Its running now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix it with

```
sudo systemctl unmask mosquitto service 
sudo service mosquitto stop 
sudo service mosquitto start
```

Its running now! – Andreas